# Tkinter: Combobox disappears when defining a callback function

Tags: class, user-interface, tkinter, combobox, callback

I'm very new to Tkinter. When I create a label and combobox on my 'Color GUI', both the label and the combobox display with no issues. The issue that I'm having is when i try to define a call back for that combobox, it disappears.

I'm just trying to practice and understand using classes, instances, and methods. Any help would be appreciated. Why is that happening?

```
 class OOP:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = tk.Tk()
        self.win.title('Color GUI')
        self.win.geometry('450x400')

# Label for choosing Color
        self.colorlabel = ttk.Label(self.win, text = 'Select a color: ',
            font =("Times New Roman", 10)).grid(column=0,
            row =1,padx=10, pady=10, sticky='W')
# Callback for color combobox
    def color_callback(self, eventObject):
        self.color_choose = eventObject.widget.get()
        if self.color_choose == 'Green':
            print('Hello World')
# Combobox creation for choosing color
        self.n = tk.StringVar
        self.colorList = ['Green', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Orange']
        self.colorchoose = ttk.Combobox(self.win, width=5, textvariable = self.n, value=self.colorList, state='readonly')
        self.colorchoose.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='W')
        self.colorchoose.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", color_callback)

#======================================================================
# Start GUI
#======================================================================
oop = OOP()
oop.win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your callback definition below the combobox creation. For now the Comboxbox creation is within the callback code.

Comment: I did, however, if i place the callback below the combo code, the code is unable to bind the callback to the combobox

Comment: @gq1108 You should use `self.color_callback` instead of `color_callback` in `bind(...)`.  Also missing `()` in `self.n = tk.StringVar`.